# SATA 3 to M.2 conversion

Tags: adapter, sata, ssd, m.2

I'm designing a PCB that should (among other things) include an M.2 SSD slot and convert that to a SATA slot to be connected to a computer. I considered just soldering a commercial SATA-M.2-adapter onto the board but I'd prefer to integrate it into the PCB design.

Would it be sufficient to directly connect the four SATA data pins to [M.2 pins](https://pinoutguide.com/HD/M.2_NGFF_connector_pinout.shtml) 41, 43, 47, 49 as well as pool all ground and 3.3V pins and connect them to the SATA power connector? (leaving all other pins unconnected)
If something more complex is required is there a commercially available IC to handle the conversion?

(also are the logic voltage levels compatible?)

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you're asking. Do you mean you have an M.2 slot, and you wish to use an external SATA drive? Adapters exist for that, with separate power for the disk (M.2 doesn't have 12V / 5V as needed for a disk.)

Comment: oh my bad. I have a SATA slot. My circuit is supposed to accept an M.2 drive and connect it to a computer via SATA. Power is supplied through a SATA power connector. I know that adapters exist for that too. I was just wondering how hard it would be to build one myself

Comment: There is an NVME M.2 and SATA M.2. Same slot, look the same at first glance, but different protocols and different speeds. If you intend to use only M.2 SATA drives, then connecting pins to pins will work. For NVMe you'll need to convert the protocols. After all, you do have a commercial piece to compare to. Look up your requirements (M.2 SATA only? M.2 NVME? Both?), look at the specs of the thing you have, that should give you an idea.